# How does await works in a for-loop?

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I just watch a `async/await` [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5Bo1Je9EmE) on youtube.

To my understanding of `await`, if `await` is in a task, when execute the task it would turn back to the event-loop while it encounter the `await` inside of the task.

So if `await` inside a for loop(that's say 10 loops), the task would be paused for 10 times, and I should use 10 `await` in the event-loop in order to finished the task, like this:

```
import asyncio

async def print_numbers():
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.25)

async def main():
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(print_numbers())
    for i in range(10):
        await task2


asyncio.run(main())
```

But, in fact the task can be done by using only 1 `await`, like this:

```
async def print_numbers():
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.25)

async def main():
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(print_numbers())
    await task2


asyncio.run(main()
```

What do I missing in this topic?

Comment: If you forget about the `async`, `await` keywords for a moment, how the non async function would work in this case? You either call it once or 10x in a loop.

Comment: When you await a task, you are waiting until the task is marked as done. It can't complete multiple times, so awaiting it in a loop doesn't do anything. In your particular example, you also don't need to create a task, you can simply `await print_numbers()`.

Comment: As for the relationship between `await` and the event loop, `await` indicates a path that _may_ yield control back to the loop, but only specific operations actually do that. In your example, the only time that will happen is when you call `asyncio.sleep`. If you removed that from `print_numbers`, the event loop wouldn't receive control back until `main` is finished.

Comment: `await` does contain a hidden loop that waits for as many suspensions as necessary for the awaitee to complete. See [this video](https://youtu.be/7JtNiwCH_OA) for a complete desugaring of `await`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it would turn back to the event-loop while it encounter the `await` inside of the task

It does, but you wait for task[0] to finish before you start task[1], so there is simply no other task in the event loop to do. So your code just ends up sleeping and doing nothing

> and I should use 10 `await` in the event-loop in order to finished the task

Yes you will need to await the 10 tasks you started, so your code will only continue once all 10 tasks are done. But you should use `asyncio.wait` or `asyncio.gather` **so the individual tasks can be parallelized** and don't have to wait for the previous one to finish.

```py
import asyncio
import random

async def print_number(i):
    print(i, 'start')
    await asyncio.sleep(random.random())
    print(i, 'done')

async def main():
    await asyncio.wait([
        asyncio.create_task(print_number(i))
        for i in range(10)
    ])
    print('main done')

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: What is  task[0] and task[1] in my instance?

Comment: My first guess is:  task[0] -> `task2` in `main()`       ;      task[1] -> None, since I didn't create other task after `task`

Comment: Second guess:task[0] -> first loop in `print_number()` ; task[1] -> second loop in `print_number()`

Comment: `main` is creating a list of 10 tasks. What I meant was `task2[0]` and `task2[1]` to `task2[9]` (the 10 `print_numbers` tasks you were tying to create)