# How can I fix the async call to OpenAI embeddings from Databricks?

Tags: python, asynchronous, databricks, openai-api

I am attempting to use the OpenAI Python package to get some embeddings for text classification.

The regular version currently works:

```
import openai
from openai.embeddings_utils import get_embedding

def add_embeddings(data:pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
  data["embedding"] = data['target_column'].apply(lambda x: get_embedding(x, engine="text-embedding-ada-002"))

  return data
```

But I wish to move to an asynchronous method, since it would be more efficient in the long term. I have attempted a few different things, but my current version looks like this:

```
import asyncio
import openai
from openai.embeddings_utils import aget_embedding

async def add_embeddings(data: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
  data["embedding"] = await asyncio.gather(*(aget_embedding(x, engine="text-embedding-ada-002") for x in data['target_column']))

  return data
```

When running the function (i.e. `data = add_embeddings(data)`) the async version returns a coroutine object instead of the expected text embeddings. I am assuming I am missing something simple, but my experience with async is quite basic.

For context I am working with Azure Databricks and have attempted to utilise the following answers:

- [Can I execute a function in "apply" to pandas dataframe asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56925702/can-i-execute-a-function-in-apply-to-pandas-dataframe-asynchronously)
- [fastest way to apply an async function to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67944791/fastest-way-to-apply-an-async-function-to-pandas-dataframe)
- [How does await works in a for-loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67240458/how-does-await-works-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: You will of course need to `data = await add_embeddings(...)`.

Comment: Thanks AKS. I did add that in, but the Databricks IDE complained about it - `" 'yield' outside function"`.

I am assuming I should ignore that?

Comment: Well, probably not – you can only await async functions within async functions (unless Databricks does that for you); see `asyncio.run()`...

Comment: I did look at `data = asyncio.run(add_embeddings(...))` but `"asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop"`...

Comment: Well, then you're already in an async context, great!

Comment: OK so in theory, then `data = add_embeddings(...)` should work? If so then why do I receive the coroutine object instead of the embeddings?

Comment: No, then `data = await add_embeddings(...)` would work.